# Similar to LoginView from WebForms in Asp.Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, webforms, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2, loginview

I have been searching but couldn't find anything about login view in razor pages. I liked login views and how easy it was to separate templates based on roles. Is there a way to do this in razor pages?

Here's LoginView from webforms example

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroups Roles="Admin">    
            <ContentTemplate>            
                Welcome Admin

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroups Roles="User">    
            <ContentTemplate> 
                Welcome User     

            </ContentTemplate>            
        </asp:RoleGroups>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Basically how to render different html for users based on their Roles

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Please revise and specify *exactly* what you want *in detail*. Provide actual examples if you can find them. Also, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and structure your question accordingly.

Comment: already  edited main post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in your views, you can use `User.IsInRole`:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
    @:Welcome Admin
}

@if (User.IsInRole("User"))
{
    @:Welcome User
}
```

Now, in terms of creating a reusable view, you either want to use a partial view or a view component. For this particular scenario, a partial view should be sufficient. View components are more appropriate when you need to inject dependencies, do custom queries or other advanced logic, none of which is necessary here.

So, create a new Razor view like `_Login.cshtml` and place your code there. Then, where you want to display that content, such as in a layout:

```
<partial name="_Login" />
```

Comment: Interesting, I'm still very new to this MVVM or MVC way of doing this with razor 'cause I come from web forms. Looks so simple and effective compared to LoginView where you couldn't access controls inside them without writing a bunch of code